# Is the order of quantifiers important in this FOL sentence?

Tags: first-order-logic

I have two sentences below. I think they are logically equivalent but I have never truly thought about the order of $\exists \forall$ vs. $\forall \exists$. Can someone verify these sentences are equivalent, and if not, please explain the difference?

- $\forall y \exists x (x < y)$
- $\exists x \forall y (x < y)$

I think they are equivalent because both $x$ and $y$ are bound by their respective quantifiers in both examples, but the difference in ordering is throwing me off. Could someone provide an example where the order of quantifiers actually does change the sentence?

Cheers.

Comment: Read "Order of quantifiers (nesting)" part in wikipedia page of quantifiers.

Answer (score 1):

No they are not! For example, "for every real number $y$ there is some real number $x$ such that $x < y$", which is the first type sentence you gave, is true; but "there is some real number $x$ such that for all real numbers $y$ we have $x < y$" is false, noting that $\mathbb{R}$ is unbounded.

Comment: I think I'm confused about the meaning in pure FOL (without superimposing interpretations). So for example, we can take two obviously equivalent sentences, both being $\forall y \exists x (x < y)$ in FOL and give them different meanings under different interpretations. For example, the sentence is true in $\mathbb{R}$ but not in $\mathbb{N}$. So by your reasoning by interpretation, the sentence is not equivalent to itself, which is obviously wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I do not think so. Order of quantifiers is very important while writing a sentence.

The two sentences that are mentioned are:

$$\forall y \exists x \left( x < y \right)$$

And

$$\exists x \forall y \left( x < y \right)$$

The first sentence can be written in English as "Given any $y$, we can find an $x$ such that $x < y$".

The other sentence can be written in English as "There is a real number $x$ such that given any $y$, $x < y$."

So, basically, in the first sentence we find an $x$ depending upon $y$. However, in the second sentence, the $x$ is universal and if we take any real number, it will be greater than $x$.

Comment: Generally, the quantifier $\exists$ means 'exists', not 'we can find'. In many problems we're able to safely assert or prove _existence_ of objects satisfying some requirements, even though we can not _construct_ or _find_ any such specific object.

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

$\forall y \exists x Parent(x,y)$ : Everyone has a parent

and:

$\exists x \forall y Parent(x,y)$ : Someone is the parent of everyone