# Question about Prenex Normal Form and Herbrand's Theorem

Tags: logic

I still have some confusion about the following concept:

Imagine we want to show that

$\exists v_0 (P v_0 \to \forall v_0 P v_0)$

is valid using Herbrand's Theorem. According to the algorithm, we transform the formula into the prenex normal form first. Now, we can simply rename the variables and apply some equivalence transformation.

$\exists v_0 (P v_0 \to \forall v_0 P v_0) \sim \exists v_0 (\lnot P v_0 \lor \forall v_1 P v_1)$

Now, can I simply put the $\forall$ quantifier at the very beginning so I can apply Herbrand's Theorem? I.e.:

$\forall v_1 \exists v_0 (\lnot P v_0 \lor P v_1)$

Because each variable is unique and there are no free variables, why does the order matter in the front of the parentheses? is this step valid or do I need another approach here?

Comment: So correct would actually be $ \exists v_0 \forall v_1(\lnot P v_0 \lor P v_1)$ ? But then I need to introducte a function $f$, i.e.  $ \exists v_0 (\lnot P v_0 \lor P f v_0)$. And without constants I cannot prove this to be valid, can I?

Comment: Also, see the first answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2840022/is-this-transformation-process-of-a-predicate-logic-formula-into-prenex-normal-f?rq=1. He also suggests putting the most right quantifier $\exists$ in front.

Comment: Although quantifier order generally matters (see Bram28's answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2486864/21813), and note that $∀y∃x(P(x)↔Q(y))$ isn't equivalent to $∃x∀y(P(x)↔Q(y))$), here, $\forall v_1 \exists v_0 (\lnot P v_0 \lor P v_1)$ and $\exists v_0 \forall v_1 (\lnot P v_0 \lor P v_1)$ are indeed equivalent.

Comment: Is there any way (like rules or similar) to be sure that switching quantifiers is valid ( $\forall v_1 \exists v_0 ( \lnot P v_0 \lor P v_1) \sim \exists v_0 \forall v_1 ( \lnot P v_0 \lor P v_1)$) or it is not (your example (∀y∃x(P(x)↔Q(y))  isn't equivalent to ∃x∀y(P(x)↔Q(y)))) ?

Comment: I should've been clearer and said "...indeed *happen to be* equivalent" instead. The two equivalent formulae are obtained by applying different choices of [Prenex rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prenex_normal_form#Conversion_to_prenex_form) on the original formula.